# Get parent's static field value via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, static

I have the following classes

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    void DoThings();
}
public class SomeImplementation1 : ISomeInterface
{
    public void DoThings() { /*..*/ }
}


public class Base
{
    public static ISomeInterface field;
}
public class Derived1 : Base
{
    static Derived1() { field = new SomeImplementation(); }
}


Type derivedType = // retrieve a type derived from Base

FieldInfo fieldInfo = derivedType.GetField("field", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); // is null
ISomeInterface a = (ISomeInterface) fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
a.DoThings();
```

So I want to get a static field value that is defined in Base, but set in Derived. At the same time I don't have a reference to initialized Derived object and have only its type.

When I try to find a corresponding field info, the result is null. As I understand, static fields are bound to the class where they were defined in. That's why I can't get field reference given a derived class.

Is there a way around this?

Some context: I work with Unity. Class Base is a MonoBehaviour and I don't want to instantiate it as it will result in performance overhead. At the same time, I want to access some logic bound to its derived classes and represented by implementations of ISomeInterface.

Comment: What about something like `typeof(Base).GetField(...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the type indicated by `derivedType` has no field `field`. This is statically bound to the `Base`-class. So you have two opportunities

1. use the base-type:

   ```
   Type derivedType = // retrieve a type derived from Base
   FieldInfo fieldInfo = derivedType.BaseType.GetField("field", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public); // is nul
   ```
2. flatten the hierarchy to get all fields from base-classes also:

   ```
   Type derivedType = // retrieve a type derived from Base
   FieldInfo fieldInfo = derivedType.GetField("field", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy);
   ```

Apart from this there´s no need to use reflection in your case, you don´t need an instance to access a static field. That´s the entire use of `static`. Just use this:

```
ISomeInterface a = Base.field;
```